# Make a widget expand to available space flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying tu put `FlutterMap` in the right widget to expand it vertically depending on the device it' been drawn on. So far it is in a Container with fixed heigh and width. 
The same I'd need to do with the Drawer as when it opens it flows outside the screen on small iPhone 6 screen.
Can you point me to a good explanation of the expanding widgets?
This is the code:

```
body: SafeArea(
          minimum: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 400,
                  width: 350,
                  child: FlutterMap()),
                Row()]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider using the **Expanded** widget
Try this

```
    SafeArea(
      minimum: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      child: Center(
      child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
              child: FlutterMap()),
        ),
        Row()]
```

Hope it works for you

Comment: Thank you , I was trying with the wrong one, `Flex`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Flutter widget `Expanded` does that for you. It has `child` argument where you can put your `Container` or `FlutterMap` widget.

Also take a look at `flex` property of `Expanded` widget if you want to create proportions for several widgets.

Comment: I accepted the other answer just because it was first. But I appreciate your help very much. I don't see a flex property in container, so I guess you meant `Expanded` widget with the `Container`in it, but yes, that will help me with the `Drawer` where I have the same problem. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Expanded is the widget I was aiming for in this case, not Container. Just edited the answer above to correct this.